# Magento not calling static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, static-block, up-sells, featured-product

I am running Magento 1.9.2.4 and it does not call some of the inbuilt static blocks.

For example the following static blocks will not display on my home page (main content area), product page (right column)

```
<!-- Upsell Items - Dynamic per slide -->

{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="You may also be interested in the following product(s)" breakpoints="[0, 2], [768, 3], [960, 4], [1280, 4]"  centered="1" is_random="1" timeout="6000" loop="1" move="4"}}
```

This has previously been working, but I can not understand why it has stopped working.

I have researched previous topics that suggest I check in system/permissions/blocks and there are two blocks listed as allowed:

1 core/template 
 2 catalog/product_new

Can anyone advise how I might be able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under System > Permissions > Blocks you need to allow the following: `ultimo/product_list_featured`

Comment: @Jimnibob please mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others ;)

Comment: in my magento 1 website now product list block is not working . In permission blocks i have allowed all blocks .

Comment: also in some fronted web pages like brand home page i am getting the following message. --->This is a custom CMS block displayed if category is empty.
You can replace it with any custom content by building CMS block
with such an id - id_category_empty.